# trouble uploading pictures or documents through Filemaker WebDirect

Tags: upload, filemaker

In my Filemaker application, I am able to upload pictures or documents using a script that imports selected the file into a field container, and then export the contents to a shared folder on the filemaker server using a serial number and file extention as the filename and a calculation container to view as thumbnail or icon.  It seems through the Filemaker Webdirect version, the export field contents script fails and was wondering if there's any acceptable alternative ways to accomplish my goal to upload files through webdirect if at all possible.

I also notice my calculation container which works brilliantly as an application but only shows as an icon in webdirect and unopenable instead.

Comment: I believe, you can't store images by reference in web direct, so you can't use managed storage/remote containers for upload. Try to embed the images and move to a remote container by a server-side script.

Comment: I see there's an option in a container to save the contents externally rather than as part of the fmp12 file so I may continue that path instead, thanks.